# Check whether an IP address is stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, ip

I have a database with a table named 'IP' in it. It has 2 columns `Id(int11)` and `ip(varchar15)`, and a row with values: `id 1, ip 127.0.0.1`

Now back in PHP I have the following:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip='$ip'";

if(mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "Ip is already in database";   
}
else {
    echo "Ip is not in database";
}
```

Now the problem I get is that the if-statement still turns TRUE if I change the IP to say: `125.0.0.1`

I have been trying to fix it for 2 hours now but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As an aside, this can be made much more efficient by storing the IP address as an integer. Use the MySQL functions [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and INET_NTOA to convert between an address and integer, and use an UNSIGNED INT column for ip. Benefits are a fixed row size, faster indexing and therefore faster lookup.

Comment: Ok nice I like faster! I will try to make it that way now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will not return false if the query executed successfully, even if there are no results. Try using [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead:

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip='$ip'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo "Ip is already in database";
}
else { 
  echo "Ip is not in database";
}
```

By the way I added `mysql_real_escape_string` around the `REMOTE_ADDR` var, you should always sanitise your input :)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply it works like a charm!
About the mysql_real_escape_string. Can someone manipulate that too?

Comment: I'm not totally sure to be honest, my instinct says it would probably be possible for someone to inject a malicious value into that variable but I'm not certain. I always err on the side of caution if I haven't explicitly set the var myself :)

Answer (score 4):

Use mysql_num_rows to check for number of records!

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip='". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ."'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num > 0) {
  echo "Exists";
}
else {
  echo "Does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wesso for the fast reply too!